# This code explain how to use Alamofire with swift.but the error is " Editor placeholder in source file" .How to solve this?

Tags: swift

```
 func downloadImage()
    {
        Alamofire.request("https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/cricket/these-five-knocks-remind-us-why-ms-dhoni-is-among-the-best-finishers-3395341.html").downloadProgress(closure:
            {
                (progress) in
                print(progress.fractionCompleted)
        })

            .responseData{ (response) in
                print(response.result)
                print(response.result.value )
        }


    }
```

Comment: I don't see any editor place holders here, I would try restarting Xcode, or if that doesn't work, cleaning your build folder and building from scratch.

Comment: Also, fix your indenting. It looks like you typed it during an earthquake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue happened with me, The issue was I mistakenly typed some spaces with special characters which are not visible in Xcode (weird but yeah it's true)

```
func downloadImage()
        {
            Alamofire.request("https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/cricket/these-five-knocks-remind-us-why-ms-dhoni-is-among-the-best-finishers-3395341.html").downloadProgress(closure:
                {
                    (progress) in
                    print(progress.fractionCompleted)
            })

                .responseData{ (response) in
                    print(response.result)
                    print(response.result.value )
            }
    //Remove your extra spaces here i think there is somthing fishy in these whitespaces 

        }
```